# Update DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, updates

I need some help.I want to update a table in `DataGridView`. I'm using this code:

```
private void UpdateData()
{                 
    cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Update Test_Rack set TestRack = '" + cboTestRack.Text + "',Number = '" + comboBox1.Text + "' ,Line = '" + textBox3.Text + "' where id = '" + rid1 + "'", DBcon);

    if (DBcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        DBcon.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DBcon.Close();
    label3.Visible = true;
    label3.Text = "Update";
    IncarcaDatele(id);
    cboTestRack.Text = "";
    comboBox1.Text = "";
    textBox3.Text = "";   
}
```

The code is working but I have a problem:it update a field and the rest are empty.

[image]

Comment: No suggestion on updating the view, but make sure to *sanitize the inputs* you're sending to the SQL Query! You're a SQL-injection-friendly target. In addition, consider using parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 2):

You missed comma `,` after `TestRack = '" + cboTestRack.Text + "'` and before `Line`.

Also I strongly recommend that you always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) like this:

```
cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Update Test_Rack set TestRack = @TestRack , ...");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestRack", cboTestRack.Text);
```

Although specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`. Check this: [`Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: by parametrized queries you mean this :
            'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestRack", cboTestRack.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", comboBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Line", textBox3.Text);'

Comment: @Ax3landra ...Yes sure. But also you should specify the parameters in the statement also like this: `set TestRack = @TestRack` , ....

Comment: or arguably better - use stored procedures

Comment: @DanielCasserly: Note that stored procedures cannot be kept under source control and would be difficult to include in code review tools to show diffs and other things.

Comment: as I said arguably better. You can strip down the permissions easier on stored procs and include a migration script in your source control. But that is an argument for another day me thinks. :-)

Comment: Still nothing.Maybe I should try to make a different user form for every field and update only one?

Comment: @Ax3landra ... Are you sure that `textBox3.Text` and your `ComboBox` are not empty during Update?

Comment: Yes.I'm sure...all the fields have an entry.When I'm trying to update a field , one it's update and the rest are empty